# Try to prove a claim

Tags: general-topology

Here is a claim:

> Let $X$ be a space with $d(X)=\mathfrak c$. If $X$ is compact and homogeneous, then for any open set $U$ of $X$ $d(U)=\mathfrak c$.

A topological space is homogeneous if for any pair of points of the space there is an autohomeomorphism of the space mapping one point to the other.

Could sombody help to prove it?

Comment: Do you require autohomeomorphisms to be surjective? (I strongly suspect that the answer is *yes*, but I want to be sure.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that there is a non-empty open $U\subseteq X$ such that $d(U)<d(X)$. Fix $x\in U$; for each $y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $h_y:X\to X$ such that $h_y(x)=y$. For $y\in X$ let $U_y=h_y[U]$; then $U_y$ is an open nbhd of $y$ of density $d(U)$. $\{U_y:y\in X\}$ is an open cover of $X$, so there is a finite $F\subseteq X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{y\in F}U_y$. But then $$d(X)=\max_{y\in F}d(U_y)=d(U)<d(X)\;,$$ which is absurd.

$X$ doesn’t have to be compact: all you really need is for $X$ to be finally $d(X)$-compact, meaning that every open cover of $X$ has a subcover of cardinality less than $d(X)$, and essentially the same argument will go through.

Comment: Why does $d(X)=\max_{y\in F} d(U_y)$ hold?

Comment: @Paul: Let $D_y$ be a dense subset of $U_y$ of cardinality $d(U_y)$; then $\bigcup_{y\in F}D_y$ is dense in $X$, and its cardinality is at most $\sum_{y\in F}d(U_y)=\max_{y\in F}d(U_y)$.

Comment: O, I see! Thanks!

Comment: @Paul: You’re welcome!